# Catalan Numbers centered String Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, catalan-numbers

### Using Catalan Numbers

*One* answer to this quesion.

In a given String these 6 conditions need to exists together:

1. String's length is 100
2. Only one curly brackets "{" is at index 1
3. Only one curly brackets "}" is at index 24
4. The rest of the brackets are rounded "("
5. Every substring that begins at index number 25 and ends at before index 50 is unbalanced ( invaild string ) and every substring that begins at index 25 and ends at index 50 is balanced ( valid string )
6. First index is "1"

**Question:** How many *options* do I have to build a valid String *concerning the conditions above?*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean by: "One answer to this quesion."? "every substring that begins at index 25 and ends at index 50 is balanced" (as the substring beginning at 25 and ending at 50 is unique)? Do you know what the Catalan numbers count?

Comment: 1. Only one good answer to this question. 2. the substring that begins at 25 and ends at 50 is valid [= balanced, like if n=4, then one of the valid options will be: " ( ( ) ) " ] . 3. yes

Comment: Then there are three valid substrings: one from 2 to 23, one from 25 to 50 with restrictions, one from 51 to 100. With Catalan numbers you know the number of options for, at least, the first and the last one.

Comment: What do you mean by Restrictions, and what about a substring from 26-49?

Comment: The restrictions are the ones in (5.).